# RNN : understanfingConcatenating layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to understanding concatenating of layers in tensorflow keras.
Below I have drew what I think is the concatenation of 2 RNN layers [ Spare for picture  clarity] and the output

[image: My model]

Here I am trying to concatenate two RNN layers. One layer has longitudinal data[ integer valued ] of patients in some time sequence and other layer has again details of same patients of other time sequence with categorical input.

I don't want these two different time sequences to be mixed up since it is medical data. So I am trying this. But before that I want to be sure if what I have drawn is what concatenating of two layers means. 
Below is my code. It appears to work well but I want to confirm if my what i drew and what is implemented are correct .

```
#create simpleRNN with one sequence of input

first_input = Input(shape=(4, 7),dtype='float32')
simpleRNN1 = layers.SimpleRNN(units=25,bias_initializer= initializers.RandomNormal(stddev=0.0001),
                           activation="relu",kernel_initializer= "random_uniform")(first_input)

#another layer of RNN
second_input = Input(shape=(16,1),dtype='float32')
simpleRNN2 = layers.SimpleRNN(units=25,bias_initializer= initializers.RandomNormal(stddev=0.0001),
                           activation="relu",kernel_initializer= "random_uniform")(second_input)

#concatenate two layers,stack dense layer on top
concat_lay = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([simpleRNN1, simpleRNN2]) 
dens_lay = layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(concat_lay)
dens_lay = layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(dens_lay)
dens_lay = layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(dens_lay)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[first_input, second_input], outputs= [dens_lay])
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',metrics=["accuracy"],lr=0.001)
model.summary()
```

Comment: So what exactly is the first question? Is it how do you implement what's in the photo with Keras? If so, can you add more details (the pictures not really clear). For example, do you need item-wise concatenation for the sequence of outputs produced by two RNNs?

Comment: Basically, I am trying to udnerstand what does concatenation of a 2 layers. Does it means that 2 layers will individually take seperate inputs and produce output upon which we can do further operations ?

Comment: Your question does not make much sense, you just drew a picture and are asking us "is this concatenation?", which is not really appropriate.

Comment: @NaveenGabriel, it would be much better if you can edit your question so that it focuses on implementing a particular type of concatenation you have in mind. This question is too broad to answer at the moment.

Comment: thanks,May be what i am trying to question is not getting through. i will update this question soon.

Comment: @thushv89 I have edited the question with my code and better picture..

Answer (score 3):

Concatenation means 'chaining together' or 'unification' here, making a union of two enities.

i think your problem is addressed in **https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/29634/how-to-combine-categorical-and-continuous-input-features-for-neural-network-trai** (*How to combine categorical and continuous input features for neural network training*)

If you have biomedical data, i.e. ECG, as the continuous data and diagnoses as the categorical data i would consider ensemble learning as the best ansatz.

What is the best solution here depends on the details of your problem ...

Building an ensembleof two neural nets is described in https://machinelearningmastery.com/ensemble-methods-for-deep-learning-neural-networks/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, what you have implemented is correct (in comparison to the diagram). To be exact it is doing the following. Here, the blue nodes denote Inputs/Outputs and `N` denote `None` (this is the batch dimension).

[image]

But just to add few notes,

- I am assuming that you want to mix the two outputs of the RNNs at the first Dense layer (with 64 units) because after that, there's no telling which input is which.
- When you use `Concatenate` as a rule of thumb specify the axis you need to concatenate on (defaults to -1). Here as you have two inputs `(None, 25)` and `(None, 25)`, axis=-1 works out fine. But it is always good to be specific, otherwise you might end up with bizarre results when you're implementing complex models.